# ListView not selecting correct row

Tags: delphi, listview, pascal

Basically I want to have a ListView populated by a StringList and when I select a ListItem and press Up or Down it moves the item up or down (in both lists).

I'm using the ListView's onKeyDown to call MoverFAT

```
procedure TF_Aplicador.ListViewKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if ListView.Selected <> nil then
    if Key = VK_UP then
      MoverFAT(ListView.Selected.Index, -1)
    else if Key = VK_DOWN then
      MoverFAT(ListView.Selected.Index, 1)
    else if Key = VK_DELETE then
      DeletarFAT(ListView.Selected.Index);
end;
```

And the issue is that when moving down it always selects the first item (after exchanging items), and moving up works just fine. FATs is my StringList and Atualizar() just makes the ListView show the contents of the StringList.

```
procedure TF_Aplicador.MoverFAT(I, J: Integer);
begin
  if ((I + J) > -1) and ((I + J) < (FATs.Count)) then
  begin
    FATs.Exchange(I, I+J);
    Atualizar;
    ListView.Selected := ListView.Items[I+J];
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I can not reproduce the described problem. I'm using procedure TForm6.ListViewData(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
begin
  Item.Caption := FATs[Item.Index];
end;  with OwnerData=true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reproduced your problem with the following `Atualizer` implementation:

```
  ListView.Clear;
  for I := 0 to FATs.Count - 1 do
    ListView.AddItem(FATs[I], nil);
```

(It sure would have been be much easier if you had given us that too.)

The problem is that the ListView itself will try to handle the key, but since you (probably) deleted all items within the `Atualizer` routine, it does not know how to.

Solve it by telling the ListView it should not handle the key stroke anymore by assigning `0`:

```
procedure TF_Aplicador.ListViewKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if ListView.Selected <> nil then
  begin
    case Key of
      VK_UP: MoverFAT(ListView.ItemIndex, -1);
      VK_DOWN: MoverFAT(ListView.ItemIndex, 1);
      VK_DELETE: DeletarFAT(ListView.ItemIndex);
    end;
    if Key in [VK_UP, VK_DOWN, VK_DELETE] then
      Key := 0;
  end;
end;
```

---

As a side note: there are better ways for synchronizing the StringList and the ListView. You could make use of the virtual approach from [Bummi's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16153617/listview-not-selecting-correct-row/16154050#comment23082318_16153617). Or you could exchange the ListView's items too, in which case you don't need to suppress the key anymore:

```
procedure TForm1.ListViewKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if ListView.Selected <> nil then
    case Key of
      VK_UP: MoverFAT(ListView.ItemIndex, -1);
      VK_DOWN: MoverFAT(ListView.ItemIndex, 1);
      VK_DELETE: DeletarFAT(ListView.ItemIndex);
    end;
end;

procedure ExchangeListItems(Items: TListItems; Index1, Index2: Integer);
var
  Item: TListItem;
begin
  Item := TListItem.Create(Items);
  try
    Item.Assign(Items[Index1]);
    Items[Index1].Assign(Items[Index2]);
    Items[Index2].Assign(Item);
  finally
    Item.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.MoverFAT(I, J: Integer);
begin
  if ((I + J) > -1) and ((I + J) < (FATs.Count)) then
  begin
    FATs.Exchange(I, I + J);
    ExchangeListItems(ListView.Items, I, I + J);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Well, though Bummi's comment was indeed a better way of doing it, yours is a lot simpler :) I still need to learn how to handle these handlers..

Answer (score 2):

as far as NGLN already pointed out the problem, I'd suggest another approach.
Don't store data in the Listview, just use it for displaying data.
Will only need a untouched Liestview and Listbox for demonstration.

```
unit Unit6;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ComCtrls, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm6 = class(TForm)
    ListView: TListView;
    ListBox1: TListBox;  // just for visualization should be an Stringlist
    procedure ListViewKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
      Shift: TShiftState);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ListViewData(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
  private
    procedure MoverFAT(I, J: Integer);
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  Form6: TForm6;

implementation

var
  FATs: TStrings;
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm6.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to 9 do
    ListBox1.Items.Add(StringOfChar(IntToStr(I)[1], 10));
  ListView.Columns.Add.Caption := 'Test';
  ListView.ViewStyle := vsList;
  ListView.OwnerData := true;
  ListView.OnData := ListViewData;
  Listview.OnKeyDown := ListViewKeyDown;
  FATs := ListBox1.Items;
  ListView.Items.Count := FATs.Count;
end;

procedure TForm6.ListViewData(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
begin
  Item.Caption := FATs[Item.Index];
end;

procedure TForm6.ListViewKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if ListView.Selected <> nil then
    if Key = VK_UP then
      MoverFAT(ListView.Selected.Index, -1)
    else if Key = VK_DOWN then
      MoverFAT(ListView.Selected.Index, 1)
end;

procedure TForm6.MoverFAT(I, J: Integer);
begin
  if ((I + J) > -1) and ((I + J) < (FATs.Count)) then
  begin
    FATs.Exchange(I, I + J);
    ListView.Invalidate;
    ListView.Selected := ListView.Items[I + J];
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: I just use the ListView to show the data. NGLN was spot-on with my issue, but thanks a lot for the help!